# AntlrWorks 2.1 - Parse Tree (GUI) not popping up

Tags: java, netbeans, antlrworks2

I am using Java 7.  Updated antlr config file to point to Java 7.
And looking at other issues on StackOverflow and elsewhere, seems like the fact that 'NetBeans' annotation-processor-compiled-with-RELEASE_6; but need 7 warning is a non-issue.

I do get these warnings in the `ANTLR TestRig (java)` Window many times, for different compiled in annotations, I guess.

Sample:

```
   warning: Supported source version 'RELEASE_6' from annotation processor 'org.netbeans.modules.openide.modules.PatchedPublicProcessor' less than -source '1.7'
```

When my grammar VCFG.g4 is opened in ANtlrworks2 - there are no warnings no errors.
Previously when I did a `run => Run in TestRig` an passed it an input file, EVEN IF the input file was invalid (didn't adhere to the grammar) ANTLRworks2 still used to pop up the tree and indicate errors in input file, if any.
 - **Help me please, get my GUI Tree back!**

More Information:

`'Show tokens', 'Print tree', 'Show tree in GUI'` => all three check-boxes are Checked.

Encoding is UTF-8 and the checkbox is CHecked as well.
The `ANTLR Codegen (java)` Window tab has no errors 
It's message:

```
Arguments: [-o, /tmp/TestRigTask-1405822965065, -lib, /home/kundan/eworkspace/antlrCentral/resources, -no-listener, -no-visitor, /home/kundan/eworkspace/antlrCentral/resources/VCFG.g4]
```

Thank you.

Comment: ANTLRWorks should work fine with Java 8. The warning you are seeing about Java 6 is a side effect of ANTLR supporting, but not requiring, Java 6.

Comment: thanks and just looked further and looks like 'netbeans' annotation components were compiled WITH java-6 and that's what the complaint is about.  Am editing the question (because problem still remains) - correcting it to ask - why tree not visible (enough though sample grammar incorrect - it used to popup earlier....

Comment: I am having the same problem with antlrworks2. I have selected the start rule correctly in the "Test Rig"dialog. can anyone throw some light ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was answered somewhere else.  After removing the Package Statement in the header and reloading the g4 in ANTLR Works 2.1, it started showing the tree.   Support for package (or other headers is probably due in future version.

Comment: You should not include a `package` statement in an ANTLR 4 grammar itself. Instead, use the `-package` command line argument when you invoke the ANTLR tool to generate your parser (the Maven plugin always does this automatically according to the location of the file in the project structure).